# Does this sentence imply that the tenant would only need to deliver the property after the expiration of the tenancy agreement?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, sentence

I found this sentence in a tenancy agreement:

> I guarantee that the Tenant shall deliver up vacant possession of the
> Property at the expiration or sooner determination of the said Tenancy
> Agreement or at any time hereafter whenever required by you.

Here "I" refers to the tenant while "you" refers to the landlord.

Does this sentence imply that the tenant would only need to deliver the property after the expiration of the tenancy agreement? Would the tenant need to deliver the property if the landlord demands the delivery before the expiration? I would appreciate it if you could break down the sentence piece-by-piece to make it easier to understand.

My understanding is that "hereafter" means "after the expiration of the tenancy agreement", so "whenever required by you" does not really mean "absolutely anytime" but "anytime after the expiration". Am I correct?

Comment: There is the other alternative 'or sooner determination of the said Tenancy Agreement' which seems very open to interpretation. Does it mean 'or to-be-decided date before the  expiry date'? If so, who has the power to determine this date? I've got to close-vote here as 'indeterminate without legal stipulations not to hand'.

Comment: I'd expect that if the final clause meant "anytime after the expiration" then it would start "at any time _thereafter_".

Comment: Does this sentence imply that the tenant would only need to deliver the property after the expiration of the tenancy agreement?  No.  / I voted to reopen, but better yet might be to delete the question here and ask it at SE.Law.  I read it to mean that the tenant has pretty much no rights!  But there are experts at SE. Law who can be quite helpful.

Comment: No. Hereafter is not thereafter.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hereafter

Comment: This is very poorly worded. As if the writer were attempting to sound like they knew what they were doing, but really didn’t.

Comment: The conditions under which *the determination of tenancy* or *the delivery of the property as required by the landlord* are not specified. Nor are any of the statutory provisions (such as period of notice) for such actions stated. These may seem like lack of necessary detail but nevertheless, it may be argued that the general meaning is clear.

Comment: What it is supposed to mean is presumably (a) the Tenant vacates and hands back the property at the expiration date stated in the agreement, and (b) if the agreement terminates at an earlier date then the Tenant vacates and hands back the property at that earlier date, and (c) if for some reason the Tenant remains in the property after either of these dates then the Tenant vacates and hands back the property when the Landlord demands it.   Whether the clause achieves this may be something a lawyer can advise on.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a meaning for this by taking it in two parts.

**I guarantee that the Tenant shall deliver up vacant possession of the Property at the [expiration (1) or sooner determination (2)]** of the said Tenancy Agreement ...

meaning that vacant possession will be given (1) when the agreement expires

or that

vacant possession will be given (2) at an earlier time than expiration. This is possible if the tenancy is one that may legally be terminated on demand. For example, some tenancies ("tenancies at will") are given indefinitely on the basis that either party may end the arrangement on demand.

Regarding the last part, your interpretation of *hereafter* as pertaining to time after the expiration is flawed. Had the agreement said *thereafter*, you might be correct to argue it meant after expiration:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thereafter)
>
> thereafter:
>
> continuing on from a particular point in time, especially after something else has stopped happening

But the agreement says *hereafter* ...

**or at [any time hereafter whenever required by you].**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hereafter)
>
> hereafter:
>
> starting from this time; in the future

meaning that vacant possession will be given at any time from **now onwards** as required by the landlord.

In summary, you give up tenancy when it expires, or when it is determined, or when asked to do so.